# how to move home screen folders to file manager?

Tags: directory, home-directory

Today Morning i using laptop then i restarting to my laptop then file manager folders coming to home screen so how to move home screen folders to main file manager please help?

Comment: Your description is hard to understand. Could you try to describe more precise what actually happened and what do you want to do? Edit your question.

Comment: looks like it might be related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483174/desktop-full-of-icons , is that what your issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Click the file on the desktop that you want to move to the file manager to mark it as selected and drag it back into the file manager with the mouse.