# Desktop full of icons

Tags: updates

Yesterday everything was neat and clean. I just had my 'personal folder' icon on the desktop. Today as I turned on my computer, the desktop is cluttered with every single possible icon.

What did just happen? How do I revert back to normal?

[image]

Comment: I tried to edit XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop" in users-dirs.dirs but it reverts back to XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/" because, guess what, I don't have a Desktop folder, which is weird.

Comment: So the solution was to create `~/Desktop` again then?

Comment: I wish. That was my first guess. I did create ~/Desktop again. First reboot worked, but then after shutting down the computer and turning back on (as in the next day), ~/Desktop is gone again and all the files back on the screen.

Comment: Another funny twist: After recreating a ~/Desktop folder, it happened again. I tried to re-create the folder a second time, but "a folder with that name already exists" although I can't see it (even displaying hidden files).